# How to add a phase shift in the digital domain?

Tags: fpga, shift-register, phase-shift

In digital beamforming, the phase shifting of a signal is done in digital domain. I am not sure about the solution that solves the problem by adding a delay to the input signal using as series of shift-register and oscillator.

If correct, would be this feasible through an FPGA module?

Comment: Wouldn't this imply synced DAQ buffers?

Comment: Dave Tweed answers this question,  but you should ask yourself what precision in timing do you need?  It very well may be you can run your clock at a rate high enough that fractional delays are not required (fir filter approach).  In some acoustic applications I have used dual port RAM where the read pointer follows the write pointer with a specified delay.

Answer (score 5):

For beamforming, you want fine control over the individual phase shifts. To get resolution down to less than the sample period, use an FIR filter. Design it with a flat frequency response and the phase shift that you want.

You can get arbitrary phase shifts this way. I once used this technique to time-align audio signals in a telecom system, where I needed phase shifts of 3/8 and 6/8 of a sample period. I was using a DSP chip at a sample rate of 8 kHz, but the same principle can be applied to RF signals using an FPGA.

Comment: Great thank Sir. I will try it. hope for good results

Answer (score 0):

Yes, adding a phase shift is equivalent to delaying a signal in the digital domain.

Yes, this can be done easily on an FPGA. Using some kind of FIFO would be the standard method.

Comment: Great thanks for your answer but I dont get what you mean. I think FIFOs are basic modules in an FPGA but they are in use for buffering data or storing them for later processing. If you make your idea on how to do it practically it will be more useful for me.